# Ssh into server from within ZeroTier network only

Tags: ssh, server, zerotier

I would like:

1) all devices within a ZeroTier network to be able to ssh into each other via ZeroTier IPs.

2) No devices from outside the network to be able to ssh into the network neither via ZeroTier IPs or standard public IPs.

The issue is that in spite of having my devices on the same ZT network, I can still ssh into those via public IP. How do I prevent this?

```
IP address for eth0:            104.xxx.xx.xxx (public IP) 
-> should not be able to ssh using this IP

IP address for ztxxxxxxxx:      10.xxx.xx.xx (ZeroTier IP)
-> should be able to ssh using this IP
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the sshd process to the ip given by zerotier to your server,

Comment: Hi Vik, thanks for your answer. The issue is that I would like to to be able to ssh into the server from any device within the ZeroTier network and from not device outside the network. Probably I need to redirect eth0 to tzXXX or something along those lines.

Comment: I've update my question above. Pardon me for poor wording.

Comment: I guess I'm a little late by now, but you should open your sshd config at "/etc/ssh/sshd_config" and replace "ListenAddress 0.0.0.0" zeros with the local IP zerotier assigned to that server, that will prevent sshd from being accessible from any other interface than the zerotier one.